# C# & WP8.1 Insert result of query select into array

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I have C# project for Windows Phone 8.1 with SQLite database.
Database contain a table, from which need select all data, and write it into array. Also have 2 classes: Links (like name of table) - contain description of table; Repository - class for methods.
I dont know how create method for inserting.
Begin like: `using (var statement = SQLiteConnection.Prepare("SELECT _id, link FROM links WHERE _id=?"))`, but what next?

Comment: Which wrapper are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what it is

Comment: On Windows Phone you would normally use SQLite with a wrapper as some sort of abstraction layer: https://github.com/koush/sqlite-net / https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple.
Use class for description table (Linkes) to create new array(type). In other class create List method with query what you need.

```
public  List <Linkses> Gettha()
        {
            List<Linkses> lin = new List<Linkses>();
            using (var statement = con.Prepare("SELECT _id, link FROM links"))
            {
                 while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
                 {
                     Linkses link = new Linkses();
                     link.Id = (long)statement[0];
                     link.Linochka = (string)statement[1];
                     lin.Add(link);
                    }
            }
            return lin;
        }
```

Then you must call that method with ToArray.

```
Linkses[] holla = App.repo.Gettha().ToArray();
```

Comment: You will possibly get error if you try to type cast a `statement` object to a `long` in this way: `link.Id = (long)statement[0];` 

Rather use this way:
`Long.parseLong(statement[0].ToString())`